# Cannot find module 'sqlite3' even though is installed

Tags: javascript, npm, command-prompt

I was trying to run the file server.js on my windows PC but I get an error from my cdm as shown below:

```
node server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\db.js
- C:\Users\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Downloads\example_backend\example_backend\db.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\example_backend\\example_backend\\db.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\example_backend\\example_backend\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

Please note that I tried to install sqlite3 but it did not solve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you have sqlite3 in the dependencies in your package.json? And you ran `npm install`? How do you use sqlite3 in the server.js file?

Comment: Hi @Geshode, thanks for replying. see my package.json as per below:   "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1"
  }

Comment: And you ran `npm install` before `node server.js`?

Comment: Yes but still no luck....

Comment: And sqlite3 is in the node_modules folder?

Comment: I cannot see any folder added apart from the ones that were already there but I did install the package

Comment: If you run `npm install` or `npm install sqlite3`, there should be a node_modules folder inside your application's root, which contains all the installed modules and their dependencies. If the node_modules folder doesn't exist or sqlite3 isn't in it, then it wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: When i try to install the package from inside the folder on my cdm it logs a bunch of warnings and errors...

Comment: Well, then please share those errors in your question (not the comments), so that we might be able to help with those.